# how to convert the string of format(2019-09-01T02:55:10.000Z) to date in plsql

Tags: plsqldeveloper

how to convert a string of format'2019-09-01T02:55:10.000Z' to date in plsql?
I tried converting using to date function but it doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at this: [To_date](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: Thanks for the information but still I am unable to convert it.Can you please help me by providing an example for that

Comment: What’s your error?

Comment: It shows not a valid date format

Comment: Could you test my answer? Then I can explain, how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
TO_DATE('2019-09-01T02:55:10.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.fffTZD')
```

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ That’s true, but before I explain, I want the answer to be proofed by OP. To be honest I haven’t tried, because I have no Oracle Db available.